# iPhone how to tell application when iPhone screen sleeps

Tags: iphone, screen, sleep, userlocation

I'm making an iPhone application that uses the user location, however I've noticed that when the iPhone screen sleeps/turns off, the phone is still using user location. So is there a function that can tell me when the screen sleeps so i can stopUpdatingLocation?

```
@interface RideauAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

Comment: Leaving the code in because it seems one of the answers requested it.

Comment: @Abizern Thanks i dont have enough privileges (yet) to do that myself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] locationManager] stopUpdatingLocation]; 
    //if it is your first VC, if not change objectAtIndex: to the correct one

}
```

Comment: Alot of useful information already covered in Stack Overflow topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411436/what-happens-to-an-iphone-app-when-iphone-goes-into-stand-by-mode

Comment: This is only a function in AppDelegate. If I used this how would I access my CLLocationManager variable in a different controller so i can call [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; ?

Comment: Is your controller a property of your delegate?

Comment: It's part of my tabBarController which is a property of my delegate

Comment: Is your tabBarController declared in your delegate? So your controller should be instanced there too?

Comment: sorry im fairly new at this and don't really know what you mean. like i just started with the default tabView App template, and added tabs in the main nib file where i connect those to my mapView.xib and my MapViewController

Comment: OK, dont worry, let me help you by posting your AppDelegate.h file

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RideauAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end

Comment: i have to go for like 30 minutes. but any help would be appreciated. thanks.. and sorry it didn't look nice when i posted my appDelegate.h

Comment: post it in your main Question, it can be better formated there.

Comment: Where is the ViewController declared? or it is just set up in Interface Builder?

Comment: ya it is all set up in interface builder

Comment: Well then it is a bit difficult to do it right, without adding too much code, try doing what ill update in my answer.

Comment: well if theres a proper way, i can change what i have

Comment: Ok, that was the _adding too much code_ i told you earlier.. Great to hear you worked it out